# How to pass ng if scope to parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

`ngIf` creates another scope inside parent scope. According to angular documentation, as I understand from this [link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngIf), is passes inside scope to parent scope in theory. But in practice, it does not. I need to pass this scope features to parent scope. How can I do that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please create an example, also I recommend using 'Controller As', and dropping scope.  It will fix a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to address this one if i understood you question (i tried). Alternatives provided.

**Approach 1 :**

you can use **$parent** inside `ng-if` and do the rest .

**Approach 2 :**

you just need to modify the structure into object notation i.e `{obj.yourval}`.

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate" ng-init="cool.mess='Im removed';checked=true">
   <br/> : {{cool.mess}}
   <br/> Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" /><br/>
  Show when checked:
  <span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
   <input type="text" ng-model="cool.mess"/>
  </span>
</body>
```

sample up for grabs **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nr27mXYp9k3suxfCqwii?p=preview)** .

**Approach 3** :

you can use `ng-hide` instead of using `ng-if` which solves all mysteries (**IMHO** be this you buddie if you have nothing to do with UI re-structuring ).

**PS:** just rounding up , docs clearly say if used `ng-if` it creates a child scope . so child can access parents data not the other way around . thats the reason why modification in child structure is not reflected at parents level . use anyone of the above alternatives .

Comment: I need to not to compile the code if ngIf experession false because it impacts the functionality not the ui so approach 3 is not the solution I am looking for. I could not understand approach 2. How this resolves the problem. Also, I am not fully comfortable with approach 1 as well. What is the advantage of $parent using inside ng-if. Thanks.

Comment: @xxlali usually `$parent` gets you the parents level data when accessed from inside child level . see again i'm stressing `inside` child as you are aware inside child scope it can have access to `only` child's data . so we use `$parent` inside child to get hold of parents data . #ng-if creates a separate instance (if used) .

Comment: I did not have time to try. When I try, if this solves my problem, I mark. Don't worry.